# sfml - vector[0].getPosition() returns 0

Tags: c++, sfml

I was making a simple snake game but when I tried moving a part of my snake
it went to 0,0. 
I keep all parts of my snake inside a vector.
But when I do something like

```
vector[0].getPosition()
//(In my code: snakeParts[0].getPosition())
```

It just returns 0,0.
I also don't get any error whilst compiling.
Here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(854, 480), "Snake");
sf::RectangleShape snake;
sf::RectangleShape snake2;

vector<sf::RectangleShape> snakeParts;

string movingDirection = "Right";

int updatePos() {

    snakeParts[1].setPosition(snakeParts[0].getPosition()); //Where my problem lies

    if (movingDirection == "Left") {
        snake.move(-32,0);
    }
    else if (movingDirection == "Right") {
        snake.move(32,0);
    }
    else if (movingDirection == "Up") {
        snake.move(0,-32);
    }
    else if (movingDirection == "Down") {
        snake.move(0,32);
    }
    //for (int i=0; i<snakeParts.size(); i++) {
        //int target = snakeParts.size()-i;
}

int main()
{
    snake.setSize(sf::Vector2f(32, 32));
    snake.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    snake2.setSize(sf::Vector2f(32, 32));
    snake2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    snakeParts.push_back(snake);
    snakeParts.push_back(snake2);

    while (App.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (App.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.close();
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {

                movingDirection = "Left";
            }
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {

                movingDirection = "Right";
            }
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
                movingDirection = "Down";
            }
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
                movingDirection = "Up";
            }

        }
        usleep(100000);
        //cout << movingDirection << endl;
        updatePos();
        App.clear();
        App.draw(snake);
        App.draw(snake2);
        App.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think it's something to do with pointers?
But I wouldn't know how I would fix that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump those global `snakeN` variables! Are you going to declare everything up to `snake100` if you want to have 100 cells? Your vector is storing copies (those are left untouched on (0, 0)), on which you should be performing all the logic.

---

Make all other global variables local to a function or member of a class and use function parameters where needed.

`movingDirection` should be an `enum`.

`updatePos` with its current signature should `return` something.